# About reading strings from a file in C

Tags: c

I have to read a file that has defined pattern: it will allways have a "Letter (single char) Number Number Number String"
For example:
 A 20 22 2340 HELLO WORLD
So i'm trying to put each thing in a separeted item of my list.

I know how to get the first char and the 3 numbers and put it into a new variable, but i don't know how to get only the final string. If i use fgets, it will get all the line and, if i use fscanf, it will get the frist "word", but it won't get anything after the space. How can i read only the string and store it into a new variable?

```
    int a, b, c, x, k = 0;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(buffer, 100, file) != NULL){
     sscanf(buffer, "%c %i %i %i ", &a, &b, &c, &x);
     Events.Key = k;
     Events.Event = a;
     Events.Day = b;
     Events.Month = c;
     Events.Year = x;
     Insertion(Events, Data); //call my function to insert in the list
     k++;
}
```

In this code, i can get the value from (my previous example) A 20 22 2340, but, if i put another %s and a string in the sscanf, it will get only "HELLO" and, if i use fgets, it will get the whole line. How can i get the whole string, including the spaces?
Thanks

Comment: `"%c ...", &a` is a type error. `%c` takes a `char *`, not an `int *`.

Comment: With `sscanf`, you need to pass the address of a `char` for `%c`, not the address of an `int`.  Your compiler should have warned about this.

Comment: You could probably do something like `char rest[100]; ... sscanf(buffer, "... %99[^\n]", ..., rest);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string set specifier `%[]` which stops scanning where you tell it. Note that `fgets()` retains the trailing newline so it is convenient to stop there, and filter it out.

```
char name[50];
if(sscanf(buffer, "%c %i %i %i %49[^\n]", &a, &b, &c, &x, name) != 5)
    {
    // handle error
    }
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Note the type error for `%c` as commented.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, guys, i used [^\n], i didn't know about that function,  thanks!